# WebAPI ModelBinder Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, modelbinder

I've implemented a `ModelBinder` but it's `BindModel()` method is not being called, and I get Error Code 500 with the following message:

**Error:**

Could not
create a 'IModelBinder' from 'MyModelBinder'. Please ensure it derives
from 'IModelBinder' and has a public parameterless
constructor.

I do derive from IModelBinder and do have public parameterless constructor.

**My ModelBinder Code:**

```
public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public MyModelBinder()
        {

        }
        public bool BindModel(ModelBindingExecutionContext modelBindingExecutionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            // Implementation
        }
    }
```

**Added in Global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new MyModelBinder();

    // ...
}
```

**WebAPI Action Signature:**

```
    [ActionName("register")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostRegister([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MyModelBinder))]User user)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

**User Class:**

```
public class User
{
    public List<Communication> Communications { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910346/mvc-4-modelbinder

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API uses a completely different ModelBinding insfracture than APS.NET MVC.

You are trying to implement the MVC's model binder interface `System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder` but to work with Web API you need to implement `System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder`

So your implementation should look like this:

```
public class MyModelBinder : System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder
{
    public MyModelBinder()
    {

    }

    public bool BindModel(
        System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext, 
        System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

For further reading:

- [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)
- [How WebAPI does Parameter Binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! it solved it, but now I can't use the DefaultModelBinder, and therefore I can't downgrade the binding to the default binder by calling base.BindModel(). I have User Model which have List<Connection>, and then it fails since the User is not of type(Connection). you have any idea?

Comment: ModelBinders are working quite differently in web.api. So in web.api there is no `DefaultModelBinder`... and usually when using web.api there are other ways exist to solve this kind of problems so you should start with the linked articles...

Comment: thanks, I am reading these articles. Feeling a bit weird that in order to use the default implementation I need make ton of logic using the built-in MediaFormatters and/or ComplexModelBinder.

Comment: This was lifesaver. Why wouldn't they just call it differently? or at least the namespace to be more insightful... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**This for using System.Web.ModelBinding**

```
 using System.Web.ModelBinding;
class clsUserRegModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
   public bool BindModel(ModelBindingExecutionContext modelBindingExecutionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

**This for System.Web.MVC**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;


class clsUserRegModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,     ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Note the Different i hope it help you**