# C# Web.API Cannot add custom model binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-binding, custom-model-binder

I have API controller that has one Put method

```
public class ScheduleExecutionsController : ApiController
{

    public ScheduleExecutionsResponse Put([ModelBinder(typeof(TestBinder))]ScheduleExecutionsRequest requestInfo)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

I added a binder class to the project

```
public class TestBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        return new ScheduleExecutionsRequest();
    }
}
```

I set 2 breakpoints. First one to the first line of Put method in controller and second to first line of my TestBinder BindModel object. 
After with Fiddler I send PUT request.

Debugger stops always inside my action but never inside BindModel methof of the binder. It seems that default binder is used. What did I miss to add custom one?

Comment: Isn't BindModel supposed to return a bool instead of an object?

Comment: no, it should be an object https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd505073(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: this link is for the Mvc documentation, the webapi doc is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.modelbinding.imodelbinder.bindmodel(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder.BindModel(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext,System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBindingContext)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a custom model binder using the \`BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext...\` signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910346/how-do-i-create-a-custom-model-binder-using-the-bindmodelhttpactioncontext-act)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the [WebAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.modelbinding.modelbinderattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) or [MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbinderattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) version of `ModelBinderAttribute`?

Most of the infrastructure of MVC and WebAPI – filters, binding, etc. – exist in two forms (due to the history of the two libraries). Your WebAPI controllers and actions *must* use the WebAPI version of these (namespace `System.Web.Http` or its child namespaces)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was a problem of wrong namespace for IModelBinder at Binder calss and also with Model binder attribute that should look like this [System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinder(typeof(TestBinder))]